# ¿Cómo declaro un combobox en ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

**¿Cuál es el comando?**

Necesito declarar un `ComboBox` en `ASP.NET`, sé que debe empezar con  `< asp:`  pero no encuentro el comando adecuando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tag correcto es `<asp:DropDownList></asp:DropDownList>`
En esta [web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx) tienes toda al documentación necesaria sobre él.

Comment: Gracias, justo lo que buscaba

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le sirve. Es un control ajax, esta la verision c# y vb.net, pego la ultima pero desde ahi pueden ir al de C#

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/combobox/how-do-i-use-the-combobox-control-vb